Unable to Install NVIDIA Geforce G210 on a fresh install of Ubuntu 24.10 newly installed from the Ubuntu 24.10 distribution
I downloaded the .iso file for Ubuntu 24.10 and then used dd to copy that file to the corresponding disk name (like
dd if=name.iso of=/dev/sdc bs=64K status=progress

) for example, using a NVIDIA AF210-1924D3L3(DDR3) graphics card.  After the fresh installation I tried logging into the GUI desktop, and I only get a cursor on the screen.
I am able to log into CTR-AlT-F3 tty3 character console only.  I have tried to make several attempts to get the driver to work for DVI and HDMI. (Note: that VGA would be a bonus, but for my particular application it does not help at all due to the monitor configurations.)
I tried several approaches (including 1) reinstalling ubuntu-desktop, 2) instaling the ubuntu-desktop and reinstalling it after that running:
sudo /etc/init.d/gdm3 restart

The live disk boots fine and its graphics driver is fine for DVI.  So the main issue seems to be a driver issue.  But I have banged my head on the wall enough to switch video cards.
Is there some way to get this card working again?
Update:  I changed video cards to the:
VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Caicos [Radeon HD 6450/7450/8450 / R5 230 OEM]
It works fine for both DVI ports. (The video card has two DVI ports and one HDMI port).  For the splash screen up-to login, it also works fine for HDMI.  After login to the graphical interface, the HDMI LG IPS Led monitor just shows blank.
The system details are as follows:
# System Details Report
---

## Report details
- **Date generated:**                              2024-11-28 13:47:05

## Hardware Information:
- **Hardware Model:**                              ASUS All Series
- **Memory:**                                      8.0 GiB
- **Processor:**                                   Intel® Core™ i3-4170 × 4
- **Graphics:**                                    AMD CAICOS
- **Disk Capacity:**                               1.1 TB

## Software Information:
- **Firmware Version:**                            1103
- **OS Name:**                                     Ubuntu 24.10
- **OS Build:**                                    (null)
- **OS Type:**                                     64-bit
- **GNOME Version:**                               47
- **Windowing System:**                            Wayland
- **Kernel Version:**                              Linux 6.11.0-9-generic

From the "Displays" section in the System Information, only the main DVI display is being recognized and not the HDMI display which makes me conclude that there is a problem with the driver after login.
From How can I find what video driver is in use on my system?
stephen@stephen-All-Series:~$ sudo lshw -c video
[sudo] password for stephen: 
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Caicos [Radeon HD 6450/7450/8450 / R5 230 OEM]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=radeon latency=0 resolution=1920,1080
       resources: irq:31 memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f7e20000-f7e3ffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:c0000-dffff

The suggestion for using 'modinfo' outputs a lot of information which does not seem helpful.  So also for this second card I am not able to get steady output once logged in.
When I first logged in everything worked so the system somehow has changed.  So now I am updating the question also for this new graphics card -- how to get it to work in the GUI environment after login.
From Reference 1 I got additional information:
stephen@stephen-All-Series:~$ hwinfo --gfxcard
12: PCI 100.0: 0300 VGA compatible controller (VGA)             
  [Created at pci.386]
  Unique ID: VCu0.3OOhiWSYJK3
  Parent ID: vSkL.xltNQFyR_DB
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0
  SysFS BusID: 0000:01:00.0
  Hardware Class: graphics card
  Model: "ATI Caicos [Radeon HD 6450/7450/8450 / R5 230 OEM]"
  Vendor: pci 0x1002 "ATI Technologies Inc"
  Device: pci 0x6779 "Caicos [Radeon HD 6450/7450/8450 / R5 230 OEM]"
  SubVendor: pci 0x174b "PC Partner Limited / Sapphire Technology"
  SubDevice: pci 0xe206 
  Driver: "radeon"
  Driver Modules: "radeon"
  Memory Range: 0xe0000000-0xefffffff (ro,non-prefetchable)
  Memory Range: 0xf7e20000-0xf7e3ffff (rw,non-prefetchable)
  I/O Ports: 0xe000-0xe0ff (rw)
  Memory Range: 0x000c0000-0x000dffff (rw,non-prefetchable,disabled)
  IRQ: 31 (117938 events)
  Module Alias: "pci:v00001002d00006779sv0000174Bsd0000E206bc03sc00i00"
  Driver Info #0:
    Driver Status: radeon is active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe radeon"
  Driver Info #1:
    Driver Status: amdgpu is active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe amdgpu"
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
  Attached to: #10 (PCI bridge)

Primary display adapter: #12

The commands
modprobe radeon 

as well as
modprobe amdgpu

just come up to a blank new line indicating perhaps some sort of problem there.
Further, I tried reinstalling the driver from the manufacturer's site giving an error which definitely suggests a driver issue; but how to fix this still?
~/Downloads/amd6450$ sudo ./AMD-Catalyst-15.9-Linux-installer-15.201.1151-x86.x86_64.run 
Created directory fglrx-install.pizySG
Verifying archive integrity... All good.
Uncompressing AMD Catalyst(TM) Proprietary Driver-15.201.1151.............................................................................
=====================================================================
 AMD Catalyst(TM) Proprietary Driver Installer/Packager 
=====================================================================

error: Detected X Server version 'XServer 1.21.1.13_64a' is not supported. Supported versions are X.Org 6.9 or later, up to XServer 1.10 (default:v2:x86_64:lib:XServer 1.21.1.13_64a:none:6.11.0-9-generic:)
Installation will not proceed.

Update:  Following one of the suggestions to improve this situation with the second video card, I referenced the following links attempting:
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/test
sudo apt update

Links:
ubuntu-14-04-5-16-04-and-newer-on-amd-graphics
downgrade-xorg-server
launchpad oibaf
launchpad ubuntu test
I filed a ticket at Oibaf Support Site after the steps below did not activate the HDMI screen:
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/test
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade

Now I am checking the suggested Downgrade X Server Instructions option.
I also tried both package updates (for example):
https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/xenial/main/updates/xserver-xorg-lts-utopic
I am not currently finding the suggestions at the top very helpful to resolve the issue.  I really need a few steps to test and then to provide feedback rather than references which have a lot of possibilities that do nsudo apt-get --purge remove octave3.2ot resolve the issue.
It seems that one of the basic difficulties that I am encountering is that I am unable to downgrade the X-Server to something supported by the manufacturer's site. The older X-Server drivers have been deleted on the ppa site it seems.
Thus on the manufacturer's driver, I am unable to get around the warning:
error: Detected X Server version 'XServer 1.21.1.13_64a' is not supported. Supported versions are X.Org 6.9 or later, up to XServer 1.10 (default:v2:x86_64:lib:XServer 1.21.1.13_64a:none:6.11.0-9-generic:)
Installation will not proceed.

The link (with one answer) downgrade X-Server link has instructions that fail:
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-lts-utopic libqt5gui5 libgles1-mesa-lts-utopic libgles2-mesa-lts-utopic libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic:i386 libglapi-mesa-lts-utopic:i386 libegl1-mesa-drivers-lts-utopic

The step to attempt to downgrade the X-server from the link results in a failure "Note, selecting 'libqt5gui5t64' instead of 'libqt5gui5'" as follows:
$ sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-lts-utopic libqt5gui5 libgles1-mesa-lts-utopic libgles2-mesa-lts-utopic libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic:i386 libglapi-mesa-lts-utopic:i386 libegl1-mesa-drivers-lts-utopic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libqt5gui5t64' instead of 'libqt5gui5'
E: Unable to locate package libgles1-mesa-lts-utopic
E: Unable to locate package libgles2-mesa-lts-utopic
E: Unable to locate package libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic
E: Unable to locate package libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic:i386
E: Unable to locate package libglapi-mesa-lts-utopic:i386
E: Unable to locate package libegl1-mesa-drivers-lts-utopic

So it seems that I need steps to downgrade the latest Ubuntu 24.10 X-Server taking in consideration what is currently posted on the X-Server site as well as to know what driver is compatible with this to get the HDMI functionality back.
Before login, HDMI shows the splash screen correctly, so I know that this is a driver problem.  I still do not have steps to solve it however.

This question is similar to: Ubuntu 14.04.5/16.04 and newer on AMD graphics. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

With older nVidia, you may want to compare to Intel's video performance. I found my Intel chip was faster for most things than my old nVidia. https://www.videocardbenchmark.net/low_end_gpus.html My Haswell Intel chip was 712 & old nVidia GT 620 only 430. Specs may be different now if updated with more samples.
